# Getting the size of a big file

Tags: java, io

Pretty basic stuff but I can't find a way to read the size of a file with several gigabytes.
I'm aware of the method `File.length`.
But int max value is **2,147,483,647**.
Is there a standard API method to read the size of a file with more than 2 gigabytes (maybe something that returns the length in kilobytes, or with Long / BigInteger)? If there isn't, which libraries are used to do that?

**Update**

People kindly pointed out that I should RTFM. Long max size can fit 8388608 terabytes. :)

Comment: You guys are right. Please Disregard

Comment: I wonder what if I have a file with 8388609 terabytes, at least in the future :\

Comment: There is likely to be a natural limit to how large a useful file can be.  Disks are getting bigger/cheaper but not so much faster. A typical disk can write 40 MB/s and a 1 GB file takes about half a minute, but a 1 TB => 8 hours, 1 PT => 1 year. Disk speeds may have improved by about 140x in the last 30 years, but it is hard to imagine a one peta-byte will be very practical and certainly not a 1 exa-byte file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`File.length()` returns a long

Answer (score 3):

According to the [`File` API doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html), `length()` returns `long`, not `int`.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that `File.length()` returns a `long`? That should be sufficient.